# How to run code if the code before it passes a try statement

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I understand that my title isn't very informative and in my opinion it is quite hard to word. In visual basic I am aiming to run a piece of code if the code before it passes the try statement but not run it if it doesn't pass the try statement.

My code is as follows:

```
Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim newCustomersRow As DataRow = Form1.Book_StoreDataSet.Customer.NewRow()
        newCustomersRow("Title") = TextBox1.Text()
        newCustomersRow("First Name") = TextBox2.Text()
        newCustomersRow("Last Name") = TextBox3.Text()
        newCustomersRow("Address Line 1") = TextBox4.Text()
        newCustomersRow("Town") = TextBox5.Text()
        newCustomersRow("County") = TextBox6.Text()
        newCustomersRow("Post Code") = TextBox7.Text()
        newCustomersRow("Card Type") = TextBox8.Text()
        newCustomersRow("Card Number") = TextBox9.Text()
        Try
            newCustomersRow("Expiry Date") = TextBox10.Text()
        Catch ex As ArgumentException
            MsgBox("Please enter date like this: DD/MM/YY.")
            TextBox1.Text = ""
            TextBox2.Text = ""
            TextBox3.Text = ""
            TextBox4.Text = ""
            TextBox5.Text = ""
            TextBox6.Text = ""
            TextBox7.Text = ""
            TextBox8.Text = ""
            TextBox9.Text = ""
            TextBox10.Text = ""
        End Try
        Try
            Form1.Book_StoreDataSet.Customer.Rows.Add(newCustomersRow)
            MsgBox("Data added successfully")
            TextBox1.Text = ""
            TextBox2.Text = ""
            TextBox3.Text = ""
            TextBox4.Text = ""
            TextBox5.Text = ""
            TextBox6.Text = ""
            TextBox7.Text = ""
            TextBox8.Text = ""
            TextBox9.Text = ""
            TextBox10.Text = ""
        Catch a As ConstraintException
            MsgBox("That Card Number already exists.")
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Every time it runs it says "Data added successfully" even if there is an error.

Comment: That is the purpose of the Try / Catch.  It allows you to handle an error and continue on without the error stopping your processing.   Move the second Try/Catch up to  inside the first Try to get your desired effect.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the issue. Ironically I tried that just as you posted your answer. Either way thank you for your help :)

Comment: @IsaSca: I'm not really a fan of that option, see my answer for details.

Comment: or call Return in the first catch

Comment: I understand you aren't a fan of that option and i have seen your answer (and listed it as the accepted one). However, I like the one suggested and have implemented it. I will use your answer in future projects. Thank you.

Comment: Try/Catch is a bad way to validate data.  You could easily use DateTime.Parse or TryParse rather than catch an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in a nutshell, you have the following problem:

```
Try
   A
Catch SomeExceptionThrownByA
   B
End Try

C?  ' only run this if there was no exception before
```

Right?

---

There are as few ways to solve this. Since, in your case, you want to skip *all* the following code, the easiest one would be:

**Option 1**

```
Try
   A
Catch SomeExceptionThrownByA
   B
   Return
End Try

C
```

Alternatives would be:

**Option 2**

```
Try
   A
   C
Catch SomeExceptionThrownByA
   B
End Try
```

or

**Option 3**

```
Dim success = False
Try
   A
   success = True
Catch SomeExceptionThrownByA
   B
End Try

If success Then
   C
End If
```

Personally, I'd prefer Option 1, if possible, and Option 3 otherwise, since it keeps the `Try-Catch` block short. I don't really like Option 2, since it

- makes it less obvious that the `Catch` block is supposed to catch errors in block `A` (instead of block `C`) and
- things get complicated if `C` can also throw `SomeExceptionThrownByA`.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you would be better served by pulling the validation out into a different method.

So (forgive syntax, my VB has been a while):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)     
     var isValid = ValidateData()
     if (!isValid) then 
        MessageBox....
        return
     end if
     try 
        Form1.Book_StoreDataSet.Customer.Rows.Add(newCustomersRow)
        ....
     catch
     ...
```

The reason I say this is what happens when you want or need to validate other data?  By separating the validation you give yourself more flexibility and keep your code cleaner.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will test this soon

Comment: That is the best answer. Don´t mix exception handling with validation handling.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest the Try/Catch go get your desired result.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim newCustomersRow As DataRow =    Form1.Book_StoreDataSet.Customer.NewRow()
    newCustomersRow("Title") = TextBox1.Text()
    newCustomersRow("First Name") = TextBox2.Text()
    newCustomersRow("Last Name") = TextBox3.Text()
    newCustomersRow("Address Line 1") = TextBox4.Text()
    newCustomersRow("Town") = TextBox5.Text()
    newCustomersRow("County") = TextBox6.Text()
    newCustomersRow("Post Code") = TextBox7.Text()
    newCustomersRow("Card Type") = TextBox8.Text()
    newCustomersRow("Card Number") = TextBox9.Text()
    Try
        newCustomersRow("Expiry Date") = TextBox10.Text()
         Try
             Form1.Book_StoreDataSet.Customer.Rows.Add(newCustomersRow)
             MsgBox("Data added successfully")
             TextBox1.Text = ""
             TextBox2.Text = ""
             TextBox3.Text = ""
             TextBox4.Text = ""
             TextBox5.Text = ""
             TextBox6.Text = ""
             TextBox7.Text = ""
             TextBox8.Text = ""
             TextBox9.Text = ""
             TextBox10.Text = ""
         Catch a As ConstraintException
             MsgBox("That Card Number already exists.")
         End Try

    Catch ex As ArgumentException
        MsgBox("Please enter date like this: DD/MM/YY.")
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""
        TextBox3.Text = ""
        TextBox4.Text = ""
        TextBox5.Text = ""
        TextBox6.Text = ""
        TextBox7.Text = ""
        TextBox8.Text = ""
        TextBox9.Text = ""
        TextBox10.Text = ""
    End Try

End Sub
 End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that use of `Try..Catch..End Try` for data validation isn't ideal. Surely it would be better to use `Date.TryParse` instead like the code below and use an `If .. End If` to check if the object already exists in your dataset?

To be honest though, using this method to catch an improperly entered date is flawed. If someone tried to enter 8th June 2016 as 08/06/2016, it  wouldnt be caught by your validity test. it might be better to use a `DateTimePicker` instead.

```
    If Not Date.TryParse(TextBox10.Text, newCustomersRow("Expiry Date")) Then
        MsgBox("Please enter date like this: DD/MM/YY.")
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""
        TextBox3.Text = ""
        TextBox4.Text = ""
        TextBox5.Text = ""
        TextBox6.Text = ""
        TextBox7.Text = ""
        TextBox8.Text = ""
        TextBox9.Text = ""
        TextBox10.Text = ""
    Else
        Try
            Form1.Book_StoreDataSet.Customer.Rows.Add(newCustomersRow)
            MsgBox("Data added successfully")
            TextBox1.Text = ""
            TextBox2.Text = ""
            TextBox3.Text = ""
            TextBox4.Text = ""
            TextBox5.Text = ""
            TextBox6.Text = ""
            TextBox7.Text = ""
            TextBox8.Text = ""
            TextBox9.Text = ""
            TextBox10.Text = ""
        Catch a As ConstraintException
            MsgBox("That Card Number already exists.")
        End Try
    End If
```